# read only property for combobox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox

What will be the code when I try to make a combo box read only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out: http://www.rajputbrotherhood.com/visual-studio-vb-.net/controls/how-to-create-a-read-only-combo-box-in-visual-studio-vbnet-free-source-code.html